# How to get the local day of week from timestamp in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ingest, scriptprocessor

I'm using the ingest pipeline script processors to extract the day of the week from the local time for each document.

I'm using the client_ip to extract the timezone, use that along with the timestamp to extract the local time, and then extract day of week (and other features) from that local time.

This is my ingest pipeline:

```
{
    "processors" : [
      {
        "set" : {
          "field" : "@timestamp",
          "override" : false,
          "value" : "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
        }
      },
      {
        "date" : {
          "field" : "@timestamp",
          "formats" : [
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC' yyyy"
          ],
          "ignore_failure" : true,
          "target_field" : "@timestamp"
        }
      },
      {
        "convert" : {
          "field" : "client_ip",
          "type" : "ip",
          "ignore_failure" : true,
          "ignore_missing" : true
        }
      },
      {
        "geoip" : {
          "field" : "client_ip",
          "target_field" : "client_geo",
          "properties" : [
            "continent_name",
            "country_name",
            "country_iso_code",
            "region_iso_code",
            "region_name",
            "city_name",
            "location",
            "timezone"
          ],
          "ignore_failure" : true,
          "ignore_missing" : true
        }
      },
      {
        "script" : {
          "description" : "Extract details of Dates",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "ignore_failure" : true,
          "source" : """
            LocalDateTime local_time LocalDateTime.ofInstant( Instant.ofEpochMilli(ctx['@timestamp']), ZoneId.of(ctx['client_geo.timezone']));
            int day_of_week = local_time.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
            int hour_of_day = local_time.getHour();
            int office_hours = 0;
            if (day_of_week<6 && day_of_week>0) { if (hour_of_day >= 7 && hour_of_day <= 19 ) {office_hours =1;}  else {office_hours = -1;}} else {office_hours = -1;}
            ctx['day_of_week'] = day_of_week;
            ctx['hour_of_day'] = hour_of_day;
            ctx['office_hours'] = office_hours;
          """
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

The first two processors were added before for other purposes. I've added the last 3.

An example document could be the following:

```
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "@timestamp": 43109942361111,
        "client_ip": "89.160.20.128"
      }
    }
  ]
```

I'm getting the GeoIP fields in the data now, but none of the fields created by the script processor. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
A few notes about the index that is affected by these changes:
The Dynamic mapping is off.
I have manually added the client_geo.timezone field to the mapping of the index as a keyword.
When I run the following scripted search on the index

```
GET index_name/_search
{
 "script_fields": {
  "day_of_week": {
    "script": "doc['@timestamp'].value.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(doc['client_geo']['timezone'])).getDayOfWeek().getValue()"
  }
 }
}
```

I get the following runtime error in script execution:

```
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "No field found for [client_geo] in mapping"
          }
```

Comment: can you add an example doc that is used as an input?

Comment: Yes, I just added one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for a well formed question + example.

I was able to replicate your problem and figured it out.

`ctx` is "The document source as it is". Consequently, ingest does not automatically dig-up dot-delimited fields.

Your client data is added as such:

```js
"client_geo" : {
   "continent_name" : "Europe"
   //<snip>..</snip>
}
```

So, you have to access it directly as a nested hash map.

Meaning `ctx['client_geo.timezone']` should actually be `ctx['client_geo']['timezone']`

Here is the full pipeline that worked for me:

```json
"processors": [
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "@timestamp",
          "override": false,
          "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
        }
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "field": "@timestamp",
          "formats": [
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC' yyyy"
          ],
          "ignore_failure": true,
          "target_field": "@timestamp"
        }
      },
      {
        "convert": {
          "field": "client_ip",
          "type": "ip",
          "ignore_failure": true,
          "ignore_missing": true
        }
      },
      {
        "geoip": {
          "field": "client_ip",
          "target_field": "client_geo",
          "properties": [
            "continent_name",
            "country_name",
            "country_iso_code",
            "region_iso_code",
            "region_name",
            "city_name",
            "location",
            "timezone"
          ],
          "ignore_failure": true,
          "ignore_missing": true
        }
      },
      {
        "script": {
          "description": "Extract details of Dates",
          "lang": "painless",
          "ignore_failure": true,
          "source": """
            LocalDateTime local_time = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(ctx['@timestamp']), ZoneId.of(ctx['client_geo']['timezone']));
            int day_of_week = local_time.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
            int hour_of_day = local_time.getHour();
            int office_hours = 0;
            if (day_of_week<6 && day_of_week>0) { if (hour_of_day >= 7 && hour_of_day <= 19 ) {office_hours =1;}  else {office_hours = -1;}} else {office_hours = -1;}
            ctx['day_of_week'] = day_of_week;
            ctx['hour_of_day'] = hour_of_day;
            ctx['office_hours'] = office_hours;
          """
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I tried this and unfortunately not much changed. However, since then, I tried using a scripted search on the final index and i get the following runtime error:
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "No field found for [client_geo] in mapping"
          }
I'll more details on that in the question.

Comment: This did solve the problem on my simulation pipeline though. The rest seems to be a problem with my mapping, so I'm gonna accept your answer.